# When will we be able to add avatar to a bot?

Tags: circuit-sdk

As a SDK users, we are using some bots in my team in order to report some things automatically in different channels, but it would help us a lot to be able to differentiate our bots thanks to an avatar.

I remember that I talked with Circuit's development team a year ago and their answer was that it should be quickly available...

Still no news about this feature that seems easy to implement and would facilitate our reading of our channels where there is multiple bots.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Tenant administrators are now able to change the bot avatar using the Circuit webclient under "Administration" > "OAuth Apps". If you cannot see the "OAuth Apps" tab, enable "OAuth Apps" in "Settings" > "Circuit Labs".

There is no option yet to change the avatar via the SDK.